# How to vertical align in a div?

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to align the text that is currently in the top left of the header so that it appears in the **bottom**. Any advise would be greatly appreciated:

This is how is appears at the moment:

[image]

This is how I want it to look:

[image]

This is code I have so far:

```
        <div id="header_container">
           <div id="subheader-left" style="float:left; width:50%; text-align:left">chilun liu</div>
              <div id="subheader-right" style="float:right; width:50%; text-align:right">
    <!-- the Social Network's images  -->  
              </div>         
           </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You have invalid markup. CSS doesn't take quotes.

Comment: @oGeez : crap man...i was about to add it!! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div

Comment: you can also make subheader-left and subheader-right absolute positioned with bottom: 0 and header_container relative.

Comment: My mistake, will fix the css syntax. Thanks everyone

Comment: @user1283674 please do remember to 'select' the answer which helped you, by clicking the tick mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

```
#subheader-left { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your existing css

```
#subheader-left,#subheader-right{
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:bottom
}
```

Side Note : This solution is supported `IE8` and above...

**Additionally**

```
style="border:none; width="40" height="40"
```

should be

```
style="border:none; width:40px; height:40px"
                      /*  ^^ no "=" sign or quotes,instead, 
                         semi colon and values only */
```

Comment: @user1283674 : glad to help fella...respond back if you still get a prob! :)